# Where I can find (track) Google Apps Script API changes and new features?

Tags: google-apps-script

Google sometimes adds/changes GAS API and I never know,when and where new functions appears..

Can i subscribe to some topic where all of these changes are in one place?

I know there is issue tracking system,but it is always only one issue at a time but it is not all updates of API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a release notes section:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases/

Comment: Wow, that is exactly I was looking for.. thank you.. Sadly, I cant give you upvote or mark you answer as solution - I guess is because I dont have enough reputation point :-(